# How to create different vhosts on nginx? (WINDOWS)

Tags: windows, webserver, winginx

So far I'm using this configuration for a server block

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  root /D:/www;
 }
```

But it's giving me this error 
403 Forbidden

nginx/1.5.12

Apparently it's reading the vhost, but it's not reading the right directory.

How can I change the directory to whatever I want?

Not root, I want it specially on D:/www/my page

IMPORTANT: I'm using windows 7, so the root directory won't be like /var/user,

My directories are D:\www\mypage

So, how should I put in the nginx config file?

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes:

```
root "D:/www/my page"
```

Answer (score 0):

Omit the drive letter and try below directive to define document root of nginx in Windows OS.

`root /www;`

Or, if your configuration is on different drive try

`root /d/www;`

If directory name contains space, enclose the path in quotes.